# Writing expanded macro with space to file

Tags: tex-core, expansion, grouping, write

I'm trying to write an expanded macro to a file without the expansion eating the space after it.

I could replace the `{}` empty group with an explicit `\space`, but I want this to be fairly robust. Is this possible to do?

I'm guessing since TeX never gets to the layout portion of the process, it doesn't know what to do with the unexpandable `{}` tokens, which is why they show up during the `\write`?

#### Example

```
% tex test.tex
\def \test {Hello}
\openout 0 hello.txt
\write 0 {\test{} World}
\end
```

#### Contents of hello.txt

```
Hello{} World
```

#### Expected

```
Hello World
```

#### Background

In broad strokes, this project is trying to retrofit a sort of note/cross-reference system to a large document with many macros and edited by many people.

```
...
\def\proj{Foobar}
\def\rev{1.0}
\def\revstr{\proj{} v\rev}
\def\complicated{...} % essentially a bunch of ifs and concats
... % A bunch of macros scattered throughout
Body of document contains macros like \proj{} and \revstr. 
The definitions of these macros are tweaked and modified.
... % A bunch of text with \notes scattered throughout,
    % also tweaked/modified, added/removed
\note{Used for callouts to \proj{} and whatever else}
...
```

The notes are currently typeset with the document, and the task is to also put them into a file for processing by an external program. For the vast majority of cases, callouts just have text and macros: no formatting or anything that couldn't be represented in ASCII.

Manually going through all the macros to replace `{}` with `\space` is somewhat out of the question, due to the volume and going against the established workflow.

The fallback is just post-process the file once TeX is done with it. Seems like the ham-fisted approach though, since TeX has all the information necessary to boil down the text.

Maybe there is a way to pretend layout a page, but then strip the content out of the boxes and put it into a file?

Comment: Welcome! What is wrong with an explicit `\space`?

Comment: It's a more fragile solution. Say I did use `\space`, but then `\test` changed to include a macro expansion itself, like `\greeting{} friend`. The same problem would come up again and *that* would need to be replaced with `\space` too. TeX seems happy with the `\test{}` convention in other places, would be nice if it could work in this scenario as well. I'm looking to use some macros like this in multiple places in the document (in addition to writing to file).

Comment: @TeXhnicallyChallenged `\space` is the choice for the business. However, it's hard to tell what your real aim is. Can you please be a bit more explicit about your project? Small “Hello world” examples are good, but not for describing complex tasks.

Comment: @egreg Added a bit of background. Hopefully that gives more insight into the project.

Comment: It is almost always best when asking here not to post disconnected fragments but to post a small self contained test file that shows the issue and can be used to test answers, although I've attempted an answer below without such a test file.

Comment: basically, using `\write` is the wrong way. `\write` doesn't do the same as the typesetting. You may have luck if your notes are really simple, but the `{}` are only *one* example of not expandable stuff that can end in the file if you don't have complete control over every command  used in the notes.  It would be better e.g. to use tex4ht to export to html or use some dvi-to.text or pdf-to-text workflow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, if it's the wrong way, it's the wrong way. I didn't know if capability was possible in TeX or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using `{}` in a write will produce `{}` that is the expected effect.

You could use `\space`  It's not clear why you expect the normal TeX tokenization not to apply here since you are expecting `\test` to be tokenized and expanded as normal. If that was not the case, you could use

```
\write20{\noexpand\test zzz}
```

which would write  `\test zzz`

But if you want `\test` to expand then

```
\write20{\test\space zzz}
```

is the simplest solution, although there areothers which can  be useful sometimes, such as

```
\def\zz#1{\write20{\test#1zzz}}\zz{ }
```

which puts a space token, rather than `\space` which expands to a space token into the argument of `\write`.

You could also (and might be what you want here) treat space tokens verbatim not as normal TeX spaces so

```
{\catcode`\ =12\relax% space is a normal punctuation character
\write20{\test zzz}%
}% back to normal
```

Comment: "It's not clear why you expect the normal TeX tokenization not to apply"-- Because I don't understand what `\write` is doing, nor the tokenization rules :) These are the sort of black magic tricks I thought might exist, however they don't quite work if `\test` is something like `\foo{} bar`

Comment: @TeXhnicallyChallenged that is the same issue: you would need to write `\foo\space bar` for the same reason.

Comment: @TeXhnicallyChallenged or define all your macros with arguments, if `\foo` is defined by `\newcommand\foo[1]{I don't use the argument}` then `\foo{} bar` will be `I don't use the argument bar`

Comment: The problem with the fake argument is that it will eat a token if the user intended there not to be a space. It also won't work if the user has `\foo\ bar`. I'm trying to avoid changing the input macros, if possible.

Comment: @TeXhnicallyChallenged if you have input that doesn't work, you need to change something, given the standard definitions the input is wrong (misusing `{}` if the text isn't being typeset) so you need to either change the input and use `\space` or change the definitions so that `{}` is removed.